# Error converting res/drawable/image.png to int

Tags: android, adapter, imagesource

I have a typed array of drawables from strings.xml that I'm trying to attach to my adapter, now I keep on getting this error.

```
08-11 16:07:50.160: E/AndroidRuntime(2120): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int:   "res/drawable-xhdpi/ico_dashboard_squared.png"
08-11 16:07:50.160: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
```

The stated drawable is correct, that's the image I need. The problem is the error.

Here's my strings.xml

```
<!-- Nav Drawer List Item Icons -->
<!-- Keep them in order as the titles are in -->
<array name="nav_drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/ico_dashboard_squared</item>
    <item>@drawable/ico_flashback</item>
    <item>@drawable/ico_qbank</item>
    <item>@drawable/ico_contact_us</item>
    <item>@drawable/ico_contact_us</item>
</array>
```

Here's how I bind it.

```
// load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);
    mDrawerListLeft.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here's the code for my adapter.

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private String[] data;
private TypedArray icoArray;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, String[] data1, TypedArray data2){
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data1;
    this.icoArray = data2;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return data.length;
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return data[position];
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(icoArray.getInteger(position, 0)); // I guess it's in this line of code       
        txtTitle.setText(data[position]);

        return convertView;
}
```

}

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: you should use..  `navMenuIcons.getResourceId(position, -1)`

Comment: Why not `icoArray.getDrawable(position)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This...

```
imgIcon.setImageResource(icoArray.getResourceId(position, 0));
```

**getResourceId(position,def value)** helps you to get ID of array in `int` value.

Answer (score -2):

You should use [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) instead of string array